# Docker - unable to (re)start Mediawiki container

Tags: docker, mediawiki

I know that start a Mediawiki container is a little hard because of the LocalSettings.php file, but I don't understand why the container started the first time but not the second one...
This is how i proceeded (using a mysql container already built):

```
docker run --name wiki --link mysql -p 81:80 -d mediawiki
```

After the installation i renamed the "old" container and typed this command:

```
docker run --name wiki --link mysql -p 81:80 -v C:/Users/u418258/Documents/DOCKER/MEDIAWIKI/LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php -d mediawiki
```

And it worked fine the first time, but after a reboot, I see this error:

```
PS C:\Users\u418258> docker start wiki
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/c/Users/u418258/Documents/DOCKER/MEDIAWIKI/LocalSettings.php\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa6ff7d9eea33ddb47bb2d635ad2ee94da6b238cd82059278ab339451067e2c9/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa6ff7d9eea33ddb47bb2d635ad2ee94da6b238cd82059278ab339451067e2c9/merged/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
Error: failed to start containers: wiki
```

I see this error also with docker run and docker start...
Can someone help me?
Thank you very much for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what OS you are on, you may want to restart Docker.

On Mac:
`killall Docker && open /Applications/Docker.app`

Or use the GUI to do so, should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it (I also rebooted the PC, Windows 10), but doesn't work.

Comment: @FID-FB What is ```-name```? Try replacing that with ```-tag```

Comment: --name is the name of the container, showed in the column "NAMES" of the output of the command "docker container ls". The "-tag" or "--tag" doesn't work for me; i get an error about syntax.